# Reading JSON: what encoding is "\u00c5\u0082"? How do I get it to a unicode object?

Tags: python, json, unicode

One of the values in a JSON file I'm parsing is `Wroc\u00c5\u0082aw`. How can I turn this string into a unicode object that yields "Wrocław" (which is the correct decoding in this case)?

Comment: `json.loads(s, encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: That prints a weird "WrocÅaw".

Comment: Those are not the proper unicode escapes for the characters you want. Whoever created that JSON did it wrong, and there's nothing sensible you can do to get it right.

Comment: Thanks, Wooble. That's pretty much all I needed to know, I figured I can just replace every \u00 in the file with \x and 1) nothing breaks, 2) things start working.

Comment: Well, that works until whatever is generating the JSON gets fixed and then your code is broken. :)

Comment: Thankfully this should be a one time thing, we're importing the json into a DB and then we'll just.. try to forget about that poor broken file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks your JSON hasn't the right encoding because neither \u00c5 nor \u0082aw yields the characters you're expecting in any encoding.

But you'd maybe try to encode this value in UTF8 or UTF16

Comment: \uc582 would yield that tricky ł, I have no idea why it's split into two.

Comment: It's a JSON encoding issue i'm pretty sure (i don't know if you produce it yourself or not, but you should have only one Utf16 caracter for ł and not two)

Comment: how ? share example.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like whatever process generated that JSON took UTF-8-encoded text and mistook it for Latin-1-encoded text. To fix the error, run the same process in reverse:

```
>>> u'Wroc\u00c5\u0082aw'.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')
u'Wroc\u0142aw'
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u0142')
'LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE'
```