# Facebook JSON badly encoded

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, mojibake

I downloaded my Facebook messenger data (in your Facebook account, go to *settings,* then to *Your Facebook information*, then *Download your information*, then create a file with at least the *Messages* box checked) to do some cool statistics

However there is a small problem with encoding. I'm not sure, but it looks like Facebook used bad encoding for this data. When I open it with text editor I see something like this: `Rados\u00c5\u0082aw`. When I try to open it with python (UTF-8) I get `RadosÅ\x82aw`. However I should get: `Radosław`.

My python script:

```
text = open(os.path.join(subdir, file), encoding='utf-8')
conversations.append(json.load(text))
```

I tried a few most common encodings. Example data is:

```
{
  "sender_name": "Rados\u00c5\u0082aw",
  "timestamp": 1524558089,
  "content": "No to trzeba ostatnie treningi zrobi\u00c4\u0087 xD",
  "type": "Generic"
}
```

Comment: Why do you assume that the data is UTF-8 ? If you don't know its encoding, have you tried other reasonable possibilities e.g. windows 1250 or ISO 8859-2?

Comment: I tried a few of them. None worked. I encountered this question asked ealier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161501/reading-json-what-encoding-is-u00c5-u0082-how-do-i-get-it-to-a-unicode-obje however I have no idea how to make it work for me

Comment: no idea if it helps, but emojies encoding seeems to be funky in facebooks api: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045268/how-does-facebook-encode-emoji-in-the-json-graph-api

Comment: @JakubJendryka: right, I'm not familiar with that system and perhaps there is indeed a mojibake in there; UTF-8 data being decoded as Latin-1 and then encoded as JSON.

Comment: @Patrick: that’s pretty much ancient history by now. We no longer use that encoding (and that only applies to Emoji).

Comment: This one did it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5396742/2297366

Comment: [For those using .NET C# solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50803989/396337)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I can indeed confirm that the Facebook download data is incorrectly encoded; a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). The original data is UTF-8 encoded but was decoded as Latin-1 instead. I’ll make sure to file a bug report.

What this means is that any non-ASCII character in the string data was encoded *twice*. First to UTF-8, and then the UTF-8 bytes were encoded *again* by interpreting them as Latin-1 encoded data (which maps exactly 256 characters to the 256 possible byte values), by using the `\uHHHH` JSON escape notation (so a literal backslash, a literal lowercase letter `u`, followed by 4 hex digits, 0-9 and a-f). Because the second step encoded byte values in the range 0-255, this resulted in a series of `\u00HH` sequences (a literal backslash, a literal lower case letter `u`, two `0` zero digits and two hex digits).

E.g. the Unicode character [U+0142 LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE](https://codepoints.net/U+0142) in the name *Radosław* was encoded to the UTF-8 byte values C5 and 82 (in hex notation), and then encoded *again* to `\u00c5\u0082`.

You can repair the damage in two ways:

1. Decode the data as JSON, then re-encode any string values as Latin-1 binary data, and then decode again as UTF-8:

   ```
    >>> import json
    >>> data = r'"Rados\u00c5\u0082aw"'
    >>> json.loads(data).encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
    'Radosław'
   ```

   This would require a full traversal of your data structure to find all those strings, of course.
2. Load the whole JSON document as binary data, replace all `\u00hh` JSON sequences with the byte the last two hex digits represent, then decode as JSON:

   ```
    import re
    from functools import partial

    fix_mojibake_escapes = partial(
        re.compile(rb'\\u00([\da-f]{2})').sub,
        lambda m: bytes.fromhex(m[1].decode()),
    )

    with open(os.path.join(subdir, file), 'rb') as binary_data:
        repaired = fix_mojibake_escapes(binary_data.read())
    data = json.loads(repaired)
   ```

   (If you are using Python 3.5 or older, you'll have to decode the `repaired` `bytes` object from UTF-8, so use `json.loads(repaired.decode())`).

   From your sample data this produces:

   ```
    {'content': 'No to trzeba ostatnie treningi zrobić xD',
     'sender_name': 'Radosław',
     'timestamp': 1524558089,
     'type': 'Generic'}
   ```

   The regular expression matches against all `\u00HH` sequences in the binary data and replaces those with the bytes they represent, so that the data can be decoded correctly as UTF-8. The second decoding is taken care of by the `json.loads()` function when given binary data.

Comment: I get 'Nedirbsiu\U0001f972' on Python version 3.8.8, but Nedirbsiu on 3.10.2, so I guess you are right. And thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @brikas: `\U0001f972` is the escape sequence for the [U+1F972 SMILING FACE WITH TEAR](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f972/index.htm) codepoint; Python 3.8 was released with Unicode 12.0.0 support and it uses `\xHH` / `\uHHHH` / `\UHHHHHHHH` escapes (plus `\n`, `\t` and `\r`) for any codepoint not marked as _printable_ in that standard. Since U+1F972 was defined in Unicode 13.0.0 Python 3.8 doesn't know it is a printable codepoint.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a command-line solution with jq and iconv. Tested on Linux.

`cat message_1.json | jq . | iconv -f utf8 -t latin1 > m1.json`

Comment: Why do you need the `jq .`? It will just pretty-print the original file

Comment: @jjmerelo You need it to convert escaped characters to their raw b0rked forms.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to extend @Geekmoss' answer with the following recursive code snippet, I used to decode my facebook data.

```
import json

def parse_obj(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        return obj.encode('latin_1').decode('utf-8')

    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [parse_obj(o) for o in obj]

    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {key: parse_obj(item) for key, item in obj.items()}

    return obj

decoded_data = parse_obj(json.loads(file))
```

I noticed this works better, because the facebook data you download might contain list of dicts, in which case those dicts would be just returned 'as is' because of the lambda identity function.

Answer (score 6):

My solution for parsing objects use [`parse_hook` callback on load/loads](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html#json.loads) function:

```python
import json


def parse_obj(dct):
    for key in dct:
        dct[key] = dct[key].encode('latin_1').decode('utf-8')
        pass
    return dct


data = '{"msg": "Ahoj sv\u00c4\u009bte"}'

# String
json.loads(data)  
# Out: {'msg': 'Ahoj svÄ\x9bte'}
json.loads(data, object_hook=parse_obj)  
# Out: {'msg': 'Ahoj světe'}

# File
with open('/path/to/file.json') as f:
     json.load(f, object_hook=parse_obj)
     # Out: {'msg': 'Ahoj světe'}
     pass
```

**Update:**

Solution for parsing list with strings does not working. So here is updated solution:

```python
import json


def parse_obj(obj):
    for key in obj:
        if isinstance(obj[key], str):
            obj[key] = obj[key].encode('latin_1').decode('utf-8')
        elif isinstance(obj[key], list):
            obj[key] = list(map(lambda x: x if type(x) != str else x.encode('latin_1').decode('utf-8'), obj[key]))
        pass
    return obj
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This issue has been driving me insane and your solution worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Martijn Pieters solution, I wrote something similar in Java.

```
public String getMessengerJson(Path path) throws IOException {
    String badlyEncoded = Files.readString(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String unescaped = unescapeMessenger(badlyEncoded);
    byte[] bytes = unescaped.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    String fixed = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return fixed;
}
```

The unescape method is inspired by the org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.

```
private String unescapeMessenger(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(str.length());
        unescapeMessenger(writer, str);
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // this should never ever happen while writing to a StringWriter
        throw new UnhandledException(ioe);
    }
}

private void unescapeMessenger(Writer out, String str) throws IOException {
    if (out == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Writer must not be null");
    }
    if (str == null) {
        return;
    }
    int sz = str.length();
    StrBuilder unicode = new StrBuilder(4);
    boolean hadSlash = false;
    boolean inUnicode = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (inUnicode) {
            unicode.append(ch);
            if (unicode.length() == 4) {
                // unicode now contains the four hex digits
                // which represents our unicode character
                try {
                    int value = Integer.parseInt(unicode.toString(), 16);
                    out.write((char) value);
                    unicode.setLength(0);
                    inUnicode = false;
                    hadSlash = false;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    throw new NestableRuntimeException("Unable to parse unicode value: " + unicode, nfe);
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (hadSlash) {
            hadSlash = false;
            if (ch == 'u') {
                inUnicode = true;
            } else {
                out.write("\\");
                out.write(ch);
            }
            continue;
        } else if (ch == '\\') {
            hadSlash = true;
            continue;
        }
        out.write(ch);
    }
    if (hadSlash) {
        // then we're in the weird case of a \ at the end of the
        // string, let's output it anyway.
        out.write('\\');
    }
}
```

Comment: So I've spent some time trying out your Java solution, only needing to debug and learning that in the larger unescapeMessenger routine, at the top of the for loop, you have an *if (inUnicode)*, which you set to false right before the loop starts ... so nothing gets processed ... what's up with that?

Comment: But the for loop block doesn't end with the first conditional block. The inUnicode variable is set to true in the second conditional block if we are on the 'u' character of the '\u' prefix.

Comment: Well, it never worked for me, I parsed out the string a different way that was crude, but effective.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook programmers seem to have mixed up the concepts of Unicode *encoding* and *escape sequences*, probably while implementing their own ad-hoc serializer. Further details in [Invalid Unicode encodings in Facebook data exports](https://krvtz.net/posts/how-facebook-got-unicode-wrong.html).

Try this:

```
import json
import io

class FacebookIO(io.FileIO):
    def read(self, size: int = -1) -> bytes:
        data: bytes = super(FacebookIO, self).readall()
        new_data: bytes = b''
        i: int = 0
        while i < len(data):
            # \u00c4\u0085
            # 0123456789ab
            if data[i:].startswith(b'\\u00'):
                u: int = 0
                new_char: bytes = b''
                while data[i+u:].startswith(b'\\u00'):
                    hex = int(bytes([data[i+u+4], data[i+u+5]]), 16)
                    new_char = b''.join([new_char, bytes([hex])])
                    u += 6

                char : str = new_char.decode('utf-8')
                new_chars: bytes = bytes(json.dumps(char).strip('"'), 'ascii')
                new_data += new_chars
                i += u
            else:
                new_data = b''.join([new_data, bytes([data[i]])])
                i += 1

        return new_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = FacebookIO('data.json','rb')
    d = json.load(f)
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is @Geekmoss' answer, but adapted for Python 3:

```
def parse_facebook_json(json_file_path):
    def parse_obj(obj):
        for key in obj:
            if isinstance(obj[key], str):
                obj[key] = obj[key].encode('latin_1').decode('utf-8')
            elif isinstance(obj[key], list):
                obj[key] = list(map(lambda x: x if type(x) != str else x.encode('latin_1').decode('utf-8'), obj[key]))
            pass
        return obj
    with json_file_path.open('rb') as json_file:
        return json.load(json_file, object_hook=parse_obj)

# Usage
parse_facebook_json(Path("/.../message_1.json"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Martijn solution #1, that I see it can lead towards recursive object processing (It certainly lead me initially):

You can apply this to the whole string of json object, if you don't `ensure_ascii`

```py
json.dumps(obj, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2).encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

then write it to file or something.

PS: This should be comment on @Martijn answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50011987/1309932 (but I can't add comments)

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach for Node 17.0.1, based on @hotigeftas recursive code, using the iconv-lite package.

```
import iconv from 'iconv-lite';

function parseObject(object) {
  if (typeof object == 'string') {
    return iconv.decode(iconv.encode(object, 'latin1'), 'utf8');;
  }

  if (typeof object == 'object') {
    for (let key in object) {
      object[key] = parseObject(object[key]);
    }
    return object;
  }

  return object;
}

//usage
let file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(fileName));
file = parseObject(file);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Martijn Pieters's answer here is the solution written in Node.js

```
import { readFileSync } from 'node:fs'
import { Buffer } from 'node:buffer'
let data = JSON.parse(readFileSync('message_1.json'),(key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
        let buff = Buffer.from(value,'latin1')
        return buff.toString('utf-8')
    } else { return value}
})
```