# Printing strings with UTF-8 encoded characters, e.g.: "\u00c5\u009b\"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I would like to print strings encoded like this one: `"Cze\u00c5\u009b\u00c4\u0087"` but I have no idea how. The example string should be printed as: "Cześć".

What I have tried is:

```
str = "Cze\u00c5\u009b\u00c4\u0087"
print(str) 
#gives: CzeÅÄ

str_bytes = str.encode("unicode_escape")
print(str_bytes) 
#gives: b'Cze\\xc5\\x9b\\xc4\\x87'

str = str_bytes.decode("utf8")
print(str) 
#gives: Cze\xc5\x9b\xc4\x87
```

Where

```
print(b"Cze\xc5\x9b\xc4\x87".decode("utf8"))
```

gives "Cześć", but I don't know how to transform the `"Cze\xc5\x9b\xc4\x87"` string to the `b"Cze\xc5\x9b\xc4\x87"` bytes.

I also know that the problem are additional backslashes in the byte representation after encoding the basis string with `"unicode_escape"` parameter, but I don't know how to get rid of them - `str_bytes.replace(b'\\\\', b'\\')` doesn't work.

Comment: Regarding your last point, `str_bytes = str_bytes.replace(b'\\\\', b'\\')` should fix that issue - you probably weren't assigning it back to a variable.

Comment: @Ihay86 Unfortunately it doesn't work. It returns the same list of bytes.

Comment: BTW, don't use `str` as a variable name, since that shadows the built-in `str` type.

Comment: The _real_ question is: Why do you have strings encoded like that? Ideally, they should be fixed upstream. You shouldn't have UTF-8 bytes encoded into a text string like that! Matias's answer works, another way to deal with this sort of mojibake is `s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')`.

Comment: @PM2Ring This is what you get if you download a copy of your Facebook information in .json format.

Comment: @PM2Ring By using Facebook interface: [Accessing & Downloading Your Information](https://www.facebook.com/help/1701730696756992)

Comment: Ok. This is a known issue, see [Facebook JSON badly encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50008296/4014959). Martijn Pieters♦, who works at Facebook, has filed an internal bug report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `raw_unicode_escape`:

```
text = 'Cze\u00c5\u009b\u00c4\u0087'
text_bytes = text.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
print(text_bytes.decode('utf8')) # outputs Cześć
```

Comment: This is JSON data, they should be decoding it as JSON. It is also a mojibake, of course, but `raw_unicode_escape` is not the right tool here and can cause issues if there are literal backslashes in the input followed by known Python escape sequences (but which JSON would have ignored).