# How can I decode this string in python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf

I downloaded a dataset of facebook messages and it was formatted like this:

```
f\u00c3\u00b8rste student
```

It's supposed to be `første student` but I cant seem to decode it correctly.

I tried:

```
str = 'f\u00c3\u00b8rste student'
print(str)
# 'fÃ¸rste student'

str = 'f\u00c3\u00b8rste student'
print(str.encode('utf-8')) 
# b'f\xc3\x83\xc2\xb8rste student'
```

But it did't work.

Comment: `'ø'` is `'\u00f8'`

Comment: Your string is in fact: 'fÃ¸rste student'

Comment: Well, I'm trying to figure out how I can get from ´\u00c3\u00b8´ to ´ø´, seeing that my whole data set is formatted like this.

Comment: Put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on top of your Python script.

Comment: @Babak when I open it in sublime it looks like f\u00c3\u00b8rste student. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Rafael That will not help `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is specifing the file encoding of the source code only.

Comment: @Prune, this is not a duplicate! that question is not the same at all. My data seem to be double encoded and to latin-1 for some reason. ARG facebook!

Comment: @Prune This is not a UTF-8 encoding issue. The issue is that there are multiple characters looking like 'ø' that are quite similar. So yes, \u00f8 is such a character, but `\xC3\xb8` too. With this the answer is obvious.

Comment: If you are sure that the original name is første, then my guess would be something has messed your source data up!

Comment: @Babak yes Im sure because its my own facebook messages that ive downloaded. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008296/facebook-json-badly-encoded) question that I think is the same problem.

Comment: @vhflat: Sorru; I reopened.

Comment: @vhflat yup... looks like you've got to encode/decode between things there... hopefully Martijn's answer helps there on the link you posted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook JSON badly encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008296/facebook-json-badly-encoded)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To undo whatever encoding foulup has taken place, you first need to convert the characters to the bytes with the same ordinals by encoding in ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) and then after that decoding as UTF-8:

```
>>> 'f\u00c3\u00b8rste student'.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')
'første student'
```