# Change encoding on JSON file when loading

Tags: json, python-3.x, encoding

I am working with my personal Facebook data, which is in JSON files with Latin-1 encoding. I would like to change the encoding to UTF-8, so I wont experience issues with scandinavian letters such as æ, ø and å.

I have looked into several questions, including this one, but I still haven't solved my problem: 
[Facebook JSON badly encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008296/facebook-json-badly-encoded)

Could anyone give some advice on how I change the encoding on a JSON file in an early stage?

Current code:

```
import json
with open('path.json', encoding='latin-1') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the JSON you are talking about, and explain what it is that you hope that "changing the encoding" would do.

Comment: Also, the answer you link to is pretty comprehensive. What about it did not work in your case?