# Fixing Facebook JSON Encoding in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, character-encoding, iconv

I'm trying to decode the JSON you get from Facebook when you download your data. I'm using Node JS. The data has lots of weird unicode escapes that don't really make sense. Example:

```
"messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "Emily Chadwick",
      "timestamp_ms": 1480314292125,
      "content": "So sorry that was in my pocket \u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0082\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0082\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0082",
      "type": "Generic"
    }
]
```

Which should decode as `So sorry that was in my pocket` . Using `fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf8")` gets me `So sorry that was in my pocket ððð` instead, which is mojibake.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008296/facebook-json-badly-encoded) mentions that it's screwed up `latin1` encoding, and that you can encode to `latin1` and then decode to `utf8`. I tried to do that with:

```
import iconv from 'iconv-lite';
function readFileSync_fixed(filename) {
    var content = fs.readFileSync(filename, "binary");
    return iconv.decode(iconv.encode(content, "latin1"), "utf-8")
}
console.log(JSON.parse(readFileSync_fixed(filename)))
```

But I still get the mojibake version. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm unfamiliar with how iconv works in regard to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved... in a way. If there's a better way to do it, let me know.

So, here's the amended function

```
readFacebookJson(filename) {
    var content = fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf8");
    const json = JSON.parse(converted)
    return json
}

fixEncoding(string) {
    return iconv.decode(iconv.encode(string, "latin1"), "utf8")
}
```

It wasn't the `readFileSync()` screwing things up, it was the `JSON.parse()`. So - we read the file as utf8 like usual, however, we then need to do the latin1 encoding/decoding on the strings that are now properties of the JSON file, not the whole JSON file before it's parsed. I did this with a `map()`.

```
messages = readFacebookJson(filename).messages.map(message => {
    const toReturn = message;
    toReturn.sender_name = fixEncoding(toReturn.sender_name)
    if (typeof message.content !== "undefined") {
        toReturn.content = fixEncoding(message.content)
    }
    return toReturn;
}),
```

The issue here is of course that some properties might be missed. So make sure you know what properties contain what.

Answer (score 1):

For this have very simple solution

Fist install `utf8` package

`npm i utf8`.

Your code will be look like this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const utf8 = require('utf8');
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('JSON_FILE_NAME');
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);

for (let i = 0;i < data["messages"].length;i++) {
    if (data["messages"][i]["content"] != undefined) {
        console.log(utf8.decode(data["messages"][i]["content"]))
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me, I would just add that this two lines:
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('JSON_FILE_NAME');
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);

Can be replaced with just:
let data = require('../folder/your_file.json');