# print characters \xc3\xb3 in json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, character-encoding

I send a non-complex json file to a web service, upon receiving the response that seems to be a json, it contains non-readable characters. I am trying to encode or decode the content to UFT8 without success, This happens when I print the content.

use: `(1)print (response.json () ['errors']. encode ('utf-8'))`

or `(2)print (response.text.encode('utf-8'))`

says:

```
(1) b'Fecha de emis\xc3\xb3n , la fecha debe ser la fecha de hoy.

(2) {"errors":"Fecha de emis\xc3\xb3n la fecha del documento debe ser la de hoy" }
```

I should say (show the tilde in ó):

```
(1) b'Fecha de emisión , la fecha debe ser la fecha de hoy.

(2) {"errors":"Fecha de emisión la fecha del documento debe ser la de hoy" }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to encode to utf-8

Comment: What is the original json?

Comment: is {"errors":"Fecha de emisión la fecha del documento debe ser la de hoy" }  {"errors":"Fecha de emis\xc3\xb3n la fecha del documento debe ser la de hoy" }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook JSON badly encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008296/facebook-json-badly-encoded)